# Getting values from objects in Razor view to Javascript/Jquery

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my view I have the following code which is loaded with properties from an object, which display just fine when I run my project.. 
But, how can I access the properties of that object in Jquery? Currently what I am getting from the console.logs is undefined.

Edit: I tried adding @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model) to my view and I can now see every prop of the object when I hit inspect in the html, but I still can´t access em in jquery.

```js
 

function EditTrabajoEnColegio(li) {
    
    console.log(li); //this displays the entire li in the console.
    //From here, I get all as undefined
    console.log(this.TrabajoId); 
    console.log(li.contrato);
    console.log(li.mesIngreso);
    console.log(li.anioIngreso);
    console.log(li.esTitular);
    console.log(li.cargoColegio);
    console.log(li.sueldoBruto);
    
    }
```

```html
 <li id="li-@Model.TrabajoId" class="list-group-item" 
 onclick="EditTrabajoEnColegio(this)">
       
            @Model.MesIngresoStJohns/@Model.AnioIngresoStJohns
            -
            @(Model.AnioEgresoStJohns != null ? 
     Model.MesEgresoStJohns.ToString() + "/" + 
      Model.AnioEgresoStJohns.ToString() : "Actualidad")
            -
            @Model.SedeNombre
            Model.TipoDocenteId 
            Model.TieneContrato          
            @Model.CargoColegio
            
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TrabajoId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SedeId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AnioEgresoStJohns)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AnioIngresoStJohns)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MesIngresoStJohns)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MesEgresoStJohns)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FechaIngreso)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FechaEgreso)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SedeNombre)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CargoColegio)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TipoDocenteId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EsTitular)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TieneContrato)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SueldoBruto)
        
    </li>
   }
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To future readers,  I was able to resolve it.

What I did was,

JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

That allowed me to pass the defined object

And in jquery

```
function EditTrabajoEnColegio(li) {
$("#CargoColegio").val(li.CargoColegio);
$("#SueldoBruto").val(li.SueldoBruto);
$("#AnioIngresoStJohns").val(li.AnioIngresoStJohns);
$("#MesIngresoStJohns").val(li.MesIngresoStJohns);
}
```

Note that the name of the parameter does not matter in jquery, it´s just something that you get from the view.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement is not very clear in the question, however what you are doing in the javascript is wrong.

```
onclick="EditTrabajoEnColegio(this)"
```

here `this` refers to the `li` object you create with razor. Therefore in the function `EditTrabajoEnColegio` `li` object will store the `li` element you pass `onclick` event. So even though you get a result from `console.log(li)` (it will print the entire li object), it will not show any values to `console.log(this.TrabajoId)` ('TrabajoId' is not a property of the li object, it is an attribute from your Model).

Accessing Model data is also possible by,

```
var data = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
```

you can now play with all the values from the Model with `data` variable just as you use a normal Json object..

Comment: I was able to reach a similar conclution yesterday (see my own answer) but I used var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); instead of JSON.parse.. is it ok or I need to use JSON parse too? and why

Comment: According to w3schools .jsonparse is the best practice. Thanks for the info.

Comment: `Json.Encode()` [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx)  will convert the object to a **string of the format of a Json**, `Html.Raw()` [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) will return you an **unencoded** string. By using `JSON.parse` you can convert this string in Json format to a **javascript object**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a javascript or jquery function such as find()

```
console.log(li.find("#TrabajoID").val());
```

Or something like :

```
$(li).find("ul").each(function( index ) {
    console.log(($(this).text());
 });
```

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: li.find is not a function
    at EditTrabajoEnColegio (PersonaEdit.js:331)
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick (119d6359-540b-4327-97af-7939b6a70a3f:536)

Comment: Oh, replace li.find("#contrato") with $(li).find("#contrato")

Comment: I´m  getting undefined on every case. For example, I just tried console.log($(li).find("#SedeNombre").val()); but got undefined

Comment: Oh wait, Are you even using jquery? You probably want to use the findElementByID() if not.

Comment: Yes, I am using Jquery.

Comment: One last thing I would suggest is to find the child in the inspector and see what parent.find("#childID) returns. I am probally off by a keystroke and that is why you aren't finding. Also, see if adding a $ prior to passing in this makes a difference --> EditTrabajoEnColegio($this). If it doesn't work then I will delete my answer as there are a million people with greater knowledge of jquery than myself.

Comment: The answer was simply JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'); thanks for the good will anyway Ross.